# how to do privilege escalation on lookup(ini)

Tags: ansible, ini

My `test.yml`

```
      1 - name: Test ini
      2   hosts: localhost
      3   connection: local
      4   become: true
      5 
      6   tasks:
      7 
      8   - name: Verifying /etc/heat/heat.conf Configuration
      9     become_user: root
     10     become_method: sudo
     11     fail: msg="Unable to set in /etc/heat/heat.conf"
     12     when: "lookup('ini', 'max_resources_per_stack section=DEFAULT file=/etc/heat/heat.conf') != '-1'"
```

Error

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [Test ini] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Verifying /etc/heat/heat.conf Configuration] ************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'lookup('ini', 'max_resources_per_stack section=DEFAULT file=/etc/heat/heat.conf') != '-1'' failed. The error was: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'ini'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>, original message: an error occurred while trying to read the file '/etc/heat/heat.conf': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/heat/heat.conf'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/stack/test.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Verifying /etc/heat/heat.conf Configuration\n    ^ here\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/stack/test.retry

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I have no idea why is it not working? ini file modification is working with `ini_file` without specifying `become_user` or `become_user`. But it is not working with `lookup`? Even I'm able run `crudini --get` command in shell too.

```
$ ls -la /etc/heat/heat.conf 
-rw-r-----. 1 root heat 85196 May 29 01:39 /etc/heat/heat.conf
```

**UPDATE**

The playbook is only working when I run playbook with `sudo` like `sudo ansible-playbook ini_test.yml`

**UPDATE2**

`ansible 2.6.11`

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question, please check

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem. As root, I'm not able to lookup file owned by `root:root` with permissions `-rw-r-----`. The error is `original message: could not locate file in lookup`. Permissions `-rw-r--r--` work fine. It's  a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10002).

With the file /root/test

```
> ll /root/test
-rw-r----- 1 root root 30 May 29 15:09 /root/test
```

The playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
    - name: read the file
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/test') }}"
```

gives (abridged):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "root"
}
TASK [read the file]
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /root/test"}
```

With all enabled to read

```
> ll /root/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30 May 29 15:09 /root/test
```

the playbook works as expected and gives (abridged):

```
TASK [read the file]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Wed May 29 15:09:43 CEST 2019"
}
```

For the record. [How should you answer questions that lead to bug reports?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132701/how-should-you-answer-questions-that-lead-to-bug-reports/).

Comment: I'm still getting same error. But I already mentioned `become: true` at the starting of playbook. Updated question with ansible version

Comment: Thanks for digging up for me. So, I guess I have use `crudini --get` :-(